# Popular and useful design patterns

Tags: python, c++, design-patterns

I want to extend my knowledge in design-patterns. I'm familiar only with Singleton and Composite.
From where should I start?
I don't know if this is relevant, but I'm a C++ and Python programmer

Comment: What design patterns are useful entirely depends on what problem you're trying to solve. There are many good books that go through each pattern and give plenty of examples on what each is good for.

Comment: purchase and read 

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Head-First-Design-Patterns-Freeman/dp/0596007124/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1415791145&sr=8-1&keywords=head+first+design+patterns

Comment: Head First is pretty Aight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are familiar with UML notation you can just try http://www.w3sdesign.com. Architecture patterns: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/

Comment: Sorry but why I've got minus for the answers?

Comment: http://www.w3sdesign.com looks good. I'll start from there